# How do I keep my form on top and prevent it from losing focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image]

If I want to make `frmLogin` without lose focus when I click at anywhere in `frmLockScreen`.

These two form are use `topmost = true` and call form `frmMainClient`.

`showDialog` is not good answer for me because it block another threads, but I just need no lose focus.

I will explain why.

I'm using [SCS Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153938/A-Complete-TCP-Server-Client-Communication-and-RMI) to build my internet cafe program

**This is what server called**

```
public void LockScreen()
        {
            var client = CurrentClient;
            client.ClientProxy.LockScreen();
        }
```

**This is what client provide to server**

```
 public void LockScreen()
        {
            _main.clearAndLockScreen();
        }
```

If I use `showDialog`, then when running it would stuck at ShowDialog() line and can't send response message back to the server because it not complete this function. Then, server will catch exeception that does't have response from client after timeout reached.

```
 public void clearAndLockScreen()
    {
        startTimeTextBox.InvokeIfRequired(s => { s.ResetText(); });
        costTextBox.InvokeIfRequired(s => { s.ResetText(); });
        memberIdLabel.InvokeIfRequired(s=>{ s.ResetText();});
        _currentElapsedTimeDisplay.InvokeIfRequired(s => 
        {
            timerManager.reset();
            s.ResetText(); 
        });
        expDateTB.InvokeIfRequired(s => { s.ResetText(); });
        remainTB.InvokeIfRequired(s => { s.ResetText(); });

        lockScreen.InvokeIfRequired(s =>
        {
            lockScreen = new LockScreen(this);
            lockScreen.Show();
        });    

        loginForm.InvokeIfRequired(s =>
        {
            loginForm = new LoginForm(this);
            loginForm.ShowDialog();
        });
        process.MoveNext(Command.Logout);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The correct solution to this problem is to show the form as a modal dialog using the `ShowDialog` method. So, what threads is `ShowDialog` blocking? Where/why do you create these threads? What is `frmLockScreen`? What exactly is your application doing?

Comment: Your question describes a problem that is solved by modality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a form that doesn't lose focus no matter what, you are out of luck.  Raymond Chen [explains this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) as a Windows design decision - it would be impossible for two programs to set their own windows as the super-topmost, so Windows doesn't let one program try either.  Now, if you are somehow modifying the built-in Windows login screen, you may have more luck, since the winlogon process has extra privileges and can indeed switch desktops, respond to Ctrl-Alt-Delete, etc.

Comment: ...But you aren't doing that with WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the owner of the frmLogin to frmLockScreen

```
frmLogin.Show(this);
frmLogin.BringToFront();
```

and then set the event for the frmLockScreen Activated to bring the frmLogin to the front?

```
private void frmLockScreen_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  frmLogin.BringToFront();
  frmLogin.Focus();    
}
```

This worked for me on an old VB Project from a few years ago, made sure the password box was always set above the form that was blocking input to the desktop, Which I guess is what you are trying to achieve.

Martyn